# multiply column by row value of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(100)
policy.1 <- data.frame(id= 1:3,
                      temperature= runif(3, min=40, max=80),
                      latitude= runif(3, min=10, max=20),
                      altitude.3= runif(3, min=50, max=70))
                      

policy.2 <- data.frame(year= (2000:2002),
                      time=c(0.81,1.25,1.87))
```

I want to multiply all cells in column `temperature` in dataframe `policy.1` by the first value of column `time` in dataframe `policy.2`. I want then to move on to column `latitude` and the second value of column `time` and so on.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: `Map(\`*\`, policy.1[,-1], policy.2$time)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the elegant solution provided in the comments by r2evans, which returns a useful list, is use `sapply`, which returns a matrix:

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(policy.2)), 
       function(x) policy.1[, x + 1] * policy.2[x, 2])

# or to overwrite policy.1:

policy.1[,-1] <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(policy.2)), 
                        function(x) policy.1[, x + 1] * policy.2[x, 2])
```

Output:

```
  id temperature latitude altitude.3
1  1    42.37162 13.20479   123.8839
2  2    40.74859 18.35687   107.3500
3  3    50.29525 18.54713   113.9413
```

(Note you could also overwrite the values using @r2evan's comment approach with `policy.1[-1] <- Map(...)`)

Comment: Thanks. I slightly updated the problem. I would appreciate if you could take a look @jpsmith. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76102971/multiply-column-by-row-value-of-another-dataframe-in-r