# multiply column by row value of another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sapply, data-wrangling

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(100)
policy.1 <- data.frame(id= 1:2450,
                      temperature.1= runif(2450, min=40, max=80),
                      temperature.2= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.3= runif(2450, min=50, max=70),
                      temperature.4= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.5= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.6= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.7= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.8= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.9= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.10= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.11= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.12= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.13= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.14= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.15= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.16= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.17= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.18= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.19= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.20= runif(2450, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.21= runif(2450, min=10, max=20))
                      

policy.2 <- data.frame(year= (2000:2020),
time=c(44,55,66,77,88,89,90,91,94,100,105,106,107,111,115,117,120,124,127,130,134))
```

I want to do the following operation on each cell of `policy.1`
I want to multiply the first row of column of `policy.1$temperature.1` by 100 and then divide it by the first row of column `policy.2$time`. I want to repeat the same operation with the next row of `policy.1$temperature.1` with the first row of column `policy.2$time`.
After I complete `policy.1$temperature.1`, I want to move on and to `policy.1$temperature.2` but this time divide by the second row of `policy.2$time`

I would also like the output as a dataframe.

Thank you

Comment: Are 2450 values necessary to illustrate the problem or would it work as well with, say, 5 rows? I think it would be a lot clearer if you had a 5x3 example instead of a 2450x21 example. And it would be much easier to verify that solutions are working as expected that way.

Comment: That would also work as well

Comment: Also you could add your expected output in this 5x3 example, so it is extra easy for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of two methods that should both scale up well:

```
## small example
set.seed(100)
n = 5
policy.1 <- data.frame(id= 1:5,
                      temperature.1= runif(5, min=40, max=80),
                      temperature.2= runif(5, min=10, max=20),
                      temperature.3= runif(5, min=50, max=70))
policy.2 <- data.frame(year= (2001:2003), time=c(44,55,66))

## solution 1 - for loop
result = policy.1
for(i in 1:(ncol(result) - 1)) {
  result[[i + 1]] = result[[i + 1]] * 100 / policy.2$time[i]
}
result
#   id temperature.1 temperature.2 temperature.3
# 1  1     118.88783      26.97765      94.69686
# 2  2     114.33386      32.95277     102.48986
# 3  3     141.12022      24.91492      84.25315
# 4  4      96.03483      28.11925      87.83297
# 5  5     133.50448      21.27749      98.86518

## solution 2 - direct replacement
result2 = policy.1
result2[-1] = t(t(result2[-1]) * 100 / policy.2$time)
result2
#   id temperature.1 temperature.2 temperature.3
# 1  1     118.88783      26.97765      94.69686
# 2  2     114.33386      32.95277     102.48986
# 3  3     141.12022      24.91492      84.25315
# 4  4      96.03483      28.11925      87.83297
# 5  5     133.50448      21.27749      98.86518
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the `sapply` tag, you could use it here:

```
policy.1[-1] <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(policy.1[-1])), 
                      function(x) (policy.1[, (x + 1)] * 100) / policy.2[x, 2])

#    id temperature.1 temperature.2 temperature.3 temperature.4 temperature.5 temperature.6 temperature.7 temperature.8 temperature.9
# 1   1     118.88783      18.58988      93.68508      19.93583      20.96160      20.57019      16.30224      13.07602      10.81159
# 2   2     114.33386      29.94727      98.96810      23.63952      12.04629      16.37650      13.80438      19.73078      14.98764
# 3   3     141.12022      25.24894      96.48128      23.85518      21.34250      11.99529      16.32598      11.91107      20.07451
# 4   4      96.03483      20.61763      87.34077      16.02036      16.43896      20.16464      18.33614      20.73747      20.96874
# 5   5     133.50448      32.24044      89.02917      15.17719      15.24028      20.61210      15.22513      20.58377      19.25159
# .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `map2_dfc`:

```
library(tidyverse)
policy.1 %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  map2_dfc(policy.2$time, ~ .x * 100 / .y) %>% 
  bind_cols(policy.1$id) %>%
  relocate(id=...22, everything())
```

```
  id temperatur…¹ tempe…² tempe…³ tempe…⁴ tempe…⁵ tempe…⁶ tempe…⁷ tempe…⁸
   <int>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1        119.     18.6    93.7    19.9    21.0    20.6    16.3    13.1
 2     2        114.     29.9    99.0    23.6    12.0    16.4    13.8    19.7
 3     3        141.     25.2    96.5    23.9    21.3    12.0    16.3    11.9
 4     4         96.0    20.6    87.3    16.0    16.4    20.2    18.3    20.7
 5     5        134.     32.2    89.0    15.2    15.2    20.6    15.2    20.6
 6     6        135.     18.7   104.     13.0    19.8    21.9    13.5    18.2
 7     7        165.     33.6   105.     23.9    16.2    21.6    18.8    16.3
 8     8        125.     27.7    77.6    14.1    15.7    21.0    16.4    19.5
 9     9        141.     34.0    79.9    18.2    21.2    13.7    20.0    14.9
10    10        106.     22.5    95.3    23.9    12.6    16.9    20.8    20.2
# … with 2,440 more rows, 13 more variables:
```